# Chrome: Text gets cut off when using non-default font-weight on a select

Tags: css, google-chrome, select, webkit-appearance

Text seems to get cut off when you use the non-default `font-weight` on a `select` in `Google Chrome`.

[image]

http://jsbin.com/wediwoqara/1/edit?html,css,output

CSS:

```
select{
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.broken {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <select class="broken">
    <option>Markets Served</option>
  </select>
  <select class="works">
    <option>Markets Served</option>
  </select>
</body>
</html>
```

`Google Chrome` Version(s):

- `Version 53.0.2785.143 (64-bit)` on `OS X (10.11.4)`
- `Version 54.0.2840.59 (64-bit)` on `OS X (10.11.4)`

As far as I can tell, this is a bug? I'd be interested if there's any sort of solution that I'm not seeing.

Comment: Seems fine on my chrome MAC . 51.0.2704.

Comment: Show your code on Stack Overflow, not on jsbin, as your jsbin link appears to go to an empty project.

Comment: Your font is a [propositional font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeface#Proportion), so it will get thicker and take more horizontal space, whereas a monospaced font wouldn't. https://jsfiddle.net/6bp25sqn/